# Trouble getting Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR

Tags: android, sqlite, calendar

I've been trying to get this to work for days and I'm tearing my hair out. I think I just need another pair of eyes to help me out.

I have "Entries" stored in a database, each with a Unix timestamp on the second they were entered. I have a system where the user can select any date and view the entries stored on the same week. The problem arises when I let the user set a custom first day of the week with `Calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek().` I can never get a correct return value from the database with the first day of the week set to something other than Sunday (for this example, I'm using Tuesday).

```
public void getEntries() {

    /* Make sure temp Calendar has same first day */
    temp = Calendar.getInstance();
    temp.setFirstDayOfWeek(date.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    /* Common date ranges in unix time */
    long oneday = 86400000L;
    long oneweek = 604800000L;
    long onemonth = 2628000000L;
    long oneyear = 31536000000L;
    /* The custom date in unix time. For example, the user may have selected Dec. 1, 2012 */
    long set_time = date.getTimeInMillis();
    entries.clear();
    dba.open();

    /* This query gets entries within 1 week and 1 day of the user-set date just to be safe */
    Cursor cc = dba.query("Date < " +(set_time+oneweek+oneday)+ " AND Date > " +(set_time-oneday-oneweek));
            if(cc.moveToFirst()) do {
                /* Set temp calendar to the timestamp of the entry in database */
                long unix = cc.getLong(1);
                temp.setTimeInMillis(unix);
                System.out.println("Temp calendar set to "+temp.getTime().toGMTString()+ " fdow("+temp.getFirstDayOfWeek()+") week("+temp.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)+"), user calendar set to "+date.getTime().toGMTString()+" fdow("+date.getFirstDayOfWeek()+") week("+date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)+")");
                if(temp.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
                && temp.get(Calendar.YEAR) == date.get(Calendar.YEAR) )
                    /* Entry object is instantiated and added to ArrayList if WEEK_OF_YEAR in temp calendar matches WEEK_OF_YEAR in global calendar */
                    entries.add(createEntryFromCursor(cc));
            } while(cc.moveToNext());

}
```

In my tests, I know for a fact there is an entry at Nov. 30, 2012. With a first day of week set to Tuesday (and the entry was on Friday), this should return 1 result if the user sets the date as 1 Dec, and no result if the user sets 26 Nov. (a Monday). However, I get 1 result for both. What's wrong?!

### Edit

I still really need help! I've updated the above with my current code. I'm still getting odd results. For example, with a first day of week as Monday, I'm getting this from `System.out`:

`12-09 11:46:38.465: I/System.out(15130): Temp calendar set to 9 Dec 2012 19:29:59 GMT fdow(2) week(49), user calendar set to 9 Dec 2012 14:51:59 GMT fdow(2) week(50)`

This is saying that 9 Dec, 2012 occurs in 2 different `WEEK_OF_YEAR`s (49/50) even though both calendars have the first day of week equal to 2. Umm.. what??

### Solution

I ditched getting the `WEEK_OF_YEAR` and followed the suggestion to get the start and end `Date`s for the week.

```
            // get rollback amt
            temp.setTimeInMillis(set_time);
            int rollback = 0;
            int dayofweek = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            while(dayofweek != temp.getFirstDayOfWeek()) {
                dayofweek--;
                if(dayofweek == 0) dayofweek = 7;
                rollback--;
            }
            int rollfwd = rollback + 6;

            // get start bound
            temp.setTimeInMillis(set_time);
            temp.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, rollback);
            temp.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            temp.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
            Date start = temp.getTime();
            // get end bound
            temp.setTimeInMillis(set_time);
            temp.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, rollfwd);
            temp.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
            temp.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
            Date end = temp.getTime();
```

Then I can check if the `Date` of the Entry is between those:

```
if(entrydate.after(start) && entrydate.before(end))
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint here, what does the expression evaluate to?  `"Date < " +(set_time+oneweek+oneday)+ " AND Date > " +(set_time-oneday-oneweek)`

Comment: Using the current time, it gets `Date < 1355074307764 AND Date > 1353691907764`

Comment: http://www.4webhelp.net/us/timestamp.php?action=stamp&stamp=13536919077&timezone=0 shows the latter as Sunday, December 20th 2398, 07:17:57 (GMT).  I suspect that set_time+oneweek+oneday is a string concatenation.

Comment: How do you set the timestamps in the database? Java `getTimeInMillis()`, or SQL `strftime('%s','now')`?

Comment: I'll test that out Simon. CL, I use the Java method.

Comment: Simon, http://www.epochconverter.com/ shows the correct times. The website you were using is somehow incorrect.

Comment: @Snailer.  Oops.  Thanks.  I should have thought to cross check.

Comment: Even if the dates are way off, as long as they're consistent (ie each date is in year 2389) I should still be able to check the week of year..

Comment: Just an observation: your `Cursor` is leaking. You need to call `cc.close()` once you're finished with it, probably in a `finally{}` block for safety.

Comment: Another observation (sorry): you can simplify your cursor loop logic. Just use `while (cc.moveToNext()) {}` at the top of the loop instead.

Comment: @Snailer : In the code where you use `System.out`, also show the return value (boolean) of the `Calendar.isLenient()` method for both the temp and user `Calendar` objects. I think it will explain why one shows week 49 and the other week 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) in android to get week_of_year and validate the conditions for querying the user selected date.

Step 1: **Get user choice for selecting the week.**
eg:27

Step 2: **get start of the week and ending of the week.**
start of 27th week to end of 27th week.

Step 3: **Use this two boundary conditions to filter your result set.**

Hope this will help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: How would I get the start and end of a week? It's easy if the first day of week is Sunday, but how would I do it dynamically for any first day of week?

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks for the suggestion.. I already knew I could do that, but I was trying to use the `Calendar` method. I just needed someone to push me ;)

Answer (score 3):

> 12-09 11:46:38.465: I/System.out(15130): Temp calendar set to 9 Dec
>   2012 19:29:59 GMT fdow(2) week(49), user calendar set to 9 Dec 2012
>   14:51:59 GMT fdow(2) week(50)

There is nearly a 5 hour difference between your Temp calendar value and your user calendar value.

You are outputting the date string using GMT:

> temp.getTime().toGMTString()

while your Calendar objects will use the local timezone.

> temp.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)+")

It is possible that these times are on the same day/week in GMT but not in your local timezone.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the days since monday of tha tweek

```
int daysSinceMonday = (7 + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - Calendar.MONDAY) % 7;
```

Use this to re-calculate the begining of your week.